# How can i make circular progress bar work in background android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, background-process

in my application there is a progress bar that should work in the background, however, only until the application is closed. In addition, a timer is tied to the progress bar, which should also change.

I tried to send the necessary variables via intent to my backgroundservice and receive them at the start of the activity, ending the background process, when closing the activity, I start the process and send the variables to the backgroundservice, however, the progress is not saved and the activity rolls back to its original form at startup
this is the code for sending and receiving variables in the activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        int h1, m1, s1, c1, i1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(TimeScreen.this, BackgroundService.class);
        h1 = intent.getIntExtra("hours1",-1);
        m1 = intent.getIntExtra("minutes1",-1);
        s1 = intent.getIntExtra("seconds1",-1);
        c1 = intent.getIntExtra("image_id1",-1);
        i1 = intent.getIntExtra("progress1",-1);
        if(h1!=-1)
            h=h1;
        if(m1!=-1)
            m=m1;
        if(s1!=-1)
            s=s1;
        if(c1!=-1)
            c=c1;
        if(i1!=-1)
            i=i1;
        stopService(intent);
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TimeScreen.this, BackgroundService.class);
        intent.putExtra("hours",h);
        intent.putExtra("minutes",m);
        intent.putExtra("seconds",s);
        intent.putExtra("progress",i);
        intent.putExtra("image_id", c);
        startService(intent);
        super.onStop();
    }
```

this is the code of my backgroundservice

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    int h,m,s,c,i;
    public BackgroundService() {
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
     }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        h = intent.getIntExtra("hours",-1);
        m = intent.getIntExtra("minutes",-1);
        s = intent.getIntExtra("seconds",-1);
        i = intent.getIntExtra("progress",-1);
        c = intent.getIntExtra("image_id",-1);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i>=0){
                    if(m>0&&s==0)
                    {
                        s=59;
                        m--;
                    }
                    if(m==0&&s==0){
                        m=59;
                        s=59;
                        h--;
                    }
                    if(s>0){
                        s--;
                    }
                    i--;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            }
        },0);
        Intent act = new Intent(this,TimeScreen.class);
        act.putExtra("hours1", h);
        act.putExtra("minutes1",m);
        act.putExtra("seconds1",s);
        act.putExtra("image_id1",c);
        act.putExtra("progress1",i);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```